# Which arm type should I'll choose?

Tags: xposed-framework

I'm trying to install a framework of xposed [here](http://dl-xda.xposed.info/framework/sdk22/)  but I'm not sure which "arm" should I choose?

My phone is lollipop 5.1 with SDK 22 but I'm not sure about its "arm" it says in an android info app its:

CPU Architecture: ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7I)

Instruction Sets:  armeabi-v7a

Kernel Architecture: armv71

Comment: Your question includes the answer I'd say: ARMv7. As it nowhere states something about 64bit, it's unlikely to be ARM64. To be on the safe side, it would help if you'd name your device.

Comment: Which device you use ?

Answer (score 1):

ARM v7 is 32-bit, ARM v8 introduced the 64-bit instruction set.